# Using Route53 for web hosting but moving email to 1&1

Tags: email-server, mx-record, amazon-route53, dns-hosting

I have recently moved a domain from 1&1 to AWS Route53.

On successful transfer, I've configured Record sets for

- MX
- NS
- SOA
- TXT
- CNAME

My understanding is that from now onwards AWS manages web hosting as well as emails. After second thought, I've decided to move Email back to 1&1. Is that possible? If so what should I do for that to work?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Route 53 doesn't host websites or email. Route 53 hosts your DNS zones.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, Route 53 is a DNS service. It is like a phone book that allows others to find your website and email server. It does not host anything but DNS.

If you want to host a website or email somewhere, configure the hosting service with that provider then update your Route53 DNS records to point to the proper hosting provider, whether that be AWS or some other provider. It does not matter.

Simply changing your domain DNS settings to Route53 did not mean, “AWS manages web hosting as well as emails.” It means AWS now hosts your DNS and that is it.